# How to check FIPS 140-2 support in OpenSSL?

Tags: linux, security, openssl, fips

We have a client which is asking about OpenSSL `FIPS (Federal Information Processing Standard) 140-2` <strike>compliant support</strike> validated cryptography use. How do I check whether OpenSSL <strike>has FIPS complains</strike> is providing FIPS validated cryptography or not?

OS: `Redhat 5 Linux`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> How do I check whether OpenSSL has is providing FIPS validated cryptography or not?

It depends on how and when you want to check. It also depends on the application.

FIPS could be available but not used. So an application must enable the validated cryptography via `FIPS_mode_set`, and the call *must* succeed.

---

If you want to check if the FIPS Capable Library, such as OpenSSL 1.0.1e, was configured to use the FIPS Object Module, then you can:

```
$ cat /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/opensslconf.h  | grep -A 2 -i fips
#ifndef OPENSSL_FIPS
# define OPENSSL_FIPS
#endif
```

`OPENSSL_FIPS` tells you the FIPS Capable Library was configured to use FIPS Object Module. So the FIPS validated cryptography is available.

`OPENSSL_FIPS` does not mean the application is using the FIPS validated cryptography, though. The application must call `FIPS_mode_set`, and the function must return success.

---

At runtime, you can print the string associated with the following (its taken from code I use specifically for this):

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT;
LogVersion(oss.str().c_str());
```

The code will produce a log entry similar to the following:

```
Version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f-fips 6 Jan 2014
```

---

You can audit the module with a few tricks. For example, the following will test for some symbols that *must* be present if executable is truly FIPS.

In this case, I'm testing the OpenSSL FIPS Capable shared object. If the application links to `libcrypto.a`, then you can audit the program rather than the OpenSSL shared object.

```
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so | grep -i fips_*
00000000000c7f60 T ERR_load_FIPS_strings
00000000000c2250 T FIPS_add_error_data
00000000000c3900 T FIPS_add_lock
0000000000082820 T FIPS_bn_bin2bn
0000000000082980 T FIPS_bn_bn2bin
0000000000082760 T FIPS_bn_clear
0000000000082350 T FIPS_bn_clear_free
00000000000823d0 T FIPS_bn_free
0000000000087c90 T FIPS_bn_generate_prime_ex
0000000000082790 T FIPS_bn_get_word
0000000000082d20 T FIPS_bn_is_bit_set
0000000000087c80 T FIPS_bn_is_prime_ex
0000000000087750 T FIPS_bn_is_prime_fasttest_ex
...
```

---

You also have the symbols from `fips_premain.c`:

```
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so | grep -i fips_text_*
00000000000c4520 T FIPS_text_end
000000000007b340 T FIPS_text_start
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so | grep -i fips_rodata*
00000000001e1e20 R FIPS_rodata_end
00000000001d8ce0 R FIPS_rodata_start
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so | grep -i fips_signature*
00000000004696c0 B FIPS_signature
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so | grep -i fips_incore*
000000000007b5a0 T FIPS_incore_fingerprint
```

---

Now, this is really sneaky. You can check that the module includes the self tests. For example, `fips_drbg_selftest.h` will include the following bytes its self tests:

```
0x2e,0xbf,0x98,0xf9,0x85,0x27,0x8b,0xff,0x36,0xb9,0x40,0x0b,
0xc0,0xa1,0xa0,0x13,0x20,0x06,0xcc,0xe6,0x2a,0x03,0x77,0x7d,
0xee,0xde,0xcc,0x34,0xe3,0xcd,0x77,0xea,0xd0,0x3e,0xbe,0xdd,
0xf6,0x15,0xfb,0xa7,0xd7,0x8e,0xd0,0x2e,0x2f,0x82,0x4c,0xc7,
0x87,0xb1,0x6f,0xc5,0xf8,0x5c,0x78,0xde,0x77,0x9b,0x15,0x9a,
0xb9,0x3c,0x38
```

---

And you can verify the developer ran `incore` or `macho_incore` on their executable to embed the FIPS fingerprint by dumping the 20 bytes of the symbol `FIPS_signature`. If its 20 bytes of 0's (the default from `fips_premain.c`), then the fingerprint was not embedded and `FIPS_mode_set` will fail. So its not possible to use FIPS validated cryptography in this case.

---

***Update***: I uploaded a slide deck I have on the subject to the OpenSSL wiki. Its called [Building Applications using OpenSSL Validated Cryptography: Notes from the Field for Developers and Auditors](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/File:Fips-validated-openssl.tar.gz). You will want to review the material starting around Slide 18.

I built the slide deck for [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org) but there's was no interest in receiving it. I know Stack Overflow frowns upon links like the one on the OpenSSL wiki, but I don't know how to provide a 35+ slide deck here.

Comment: If I issue `openssl version`, the system returns: `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`.   Is this just telling me that I have an openssl library capaple of FIPS 140-2?   Why would it indicate this if the FIPS module isn't yet built/configured?

Comment: The same version is returned whether fips is enabled or not.  This ^^ is on a CentOS 6 system.

Comment: I would add that if you simply want to confirm that your openssl is 'fips enabled' then you can run `env OPENSSL_FIPS=1 openssl md5 <some file>`.  A fips enabled openssl will then enter fips mode and throw an error as md5 is not a valid cipher.

Comment: @TejayCardon Do you mean "env OPENSSL_FIPS=1 openssl md5 <some file>" will check if openssl is "FIPS capable" but not necessarily running in FIPS mode? I assume if this - "env openssl md5 <some file>" fails witl FIPS error, openssl is truly running in FIPS mode.

Comment: It means with fips-enabled, the command-line openssl utility does not offer md5 support, and will not work. Ex: `openssl md5 <<< "12345"` will deliver `(stdin)= d577273ff885c3f84dadb8578bb41399` as the result. With fips-mode enabled (and using a properly built fips openssl), `env OPENSSL_FIPS=1 openssl md5 <<< "12345"` will result in `Error setting digest md5 4677500524:error:060A80A3:digital envelope routines:FIPS_DIGESTINIT:disabled for fips:fips_md.c:180:`, wheres a supported algorithm (ex: sha256) will still work.

Answer (score 11):

To check if openssl is operating under fips mode,  issue the following:

```
$ openssl md5 somefile
```

The above should fail as MD5 is not a fips approved Hash Standard.

```
$ openssl sha1 somefile
```

The above would work as SHA1 is the fips Approved Hash Standard.

**Example**:

```
# openssl md5 message.txt
Error setting digest md5
140062425388872:error:060800A3:digital envelope routines:EVP_DigestInit_ex:disabled for fips:digest.c:251:

# openssl sha1 message.txt 
SHA1(messagetext.txt)= 9f5080758dbf71537cc44a4d8cb67564f2ad938a
```

[Reference](https://niranjanmr.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/rhel6-fips/)

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSL itself is not FIPS 140-2 validated and, according to it's maintainers, will never be. However, it has a FIPS 140-2 validated module called the FIPS Object Module, that partly replaces *libcrypto* used in vanilla OpenSSL. More information, including [user guide](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf), can be found [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html). In short:

> OpenSSL itself is not validated, and never will be. Instead a special
>   carefully defined software component called the OpenSSL FIPS Object
>   Module has been created. This Module was designed for compatibility
>   with OpenSSL so that products using the OpenSSL API can be converted
>   to use validated cryptography with minimal effort.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using dynamic linking, this c code will check for you:

```
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  if (FIPS_mode() || FIPS_mode_set(1)) {
    printf("Installed library has FIPS support\n");
    return 0;
  }

  const char* err_str = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), 0);
  printf("Failed to enable FIPS mode, %s\n", err_str);
  if (strstr(err_str, "0F06D065")) {
    printf("Installed library does not have FIPS support\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

On Linux you can compile and run via:

Compile like so:

`gcc fips_openssl_check.c -lcrypto`

or

`gcc fips_openssl_check.c -l:libcrypto.so.1.0.2`

if you have multiple libcrypto versions installed and want to check a specific one. Other compilers such as clang are fine too.

Execute to perform the check:

`./a.out`

https://github.com/ericcurtin/fips_openssl_check

Answer (score 1):

Kernel option "*fips=1*" should be enabled.  A bit more on that [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/chap-Federal_Standards_and_Regulations.html#sec-Enabling-FIPS-Mode).

To see if that is loaded:

```
sudo sysctl -a|grep fips
```

Answer (score 1):

The Openssl 3.0 series has removed these

- FIPS_mode()
- FIPS_mode_set()

These functions are legacy APIs that are not applicable to the new provider model. Applications should instead use

- EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled()
- EVP_default_properties_enable_fips()

For example,

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Check if FIPS mode is enabled in the default library context
    int fipsEnabled = EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled(NULL);
    if (fipsEnabled) {
        printf("FIPS mode is enabled.\n");
    } else {
        printf("FIPS mode is not enabled.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what i found to check support.

```
# openssl ciphers FIPS -v
ADH-AES256-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ADH-AES128-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=KRB5     Au=KRB5 Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

Comment: How does this show that the FIPS 140-2 module has been built and configured?  Wouldn't I see the exact same result on a standard OpenSSL binary?

Comment: @acoder it does not include md5 for FIPS ciphers, so you know by what is missing.