# FIPS integrity verification test failed when iniating SSH session

Tags: ssh, openssl, centos, centos6, fips

I recently [enabled](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Federal_Standards_And_Regulations-Federal_Information_Processing_Standard.html) the FIPS module under CentOS 6 (minimum install).

Module is [confirmed working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616573/how-to-check-fips-140-2-support-in-openssl/):

`cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled` yields `1`

`openssl md5 somefile`(fails) and `openssl sha1 somefile`(succeeds).

`openssl version` yields `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`

When I attempt to ssh into a box I connect to daily, I now see a notice stating:

> FIPS integrity verification test failed

The session continues and I am able to connect to the remote server.  Is the connection still secure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The session continues and I am able to connect to the remote server. Is the connection still secure?

Yes.

OpenSSL is known as FIPS Capable. The FIPS Capable version of the library can use validated cryptography.

If `FIPS_mode_set` is not called, then the module is using non-validated cryptography. If `FIPS_mode_set` is called but fails (your situation), then the module using non-validated cryptography. In both case you are using cryptography, its just not blessed by FIPS.