# when i do a "git pull origin" it gives a permission denied . How can i resolve this?

Tags: git

When i do a git pull origin, I see below error. I checked the permissions of ".git" folder and keys and config. It was working working for few years now. All of sudden it started giving this error. This works from the windows machine. So i am guessing the connectivity is not an issue.

"FIPS integrity verification test failed

Permission denied (keyboard-interactive,publickey)

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Comment: It looks like the credentials with which you authenticate yourself against the origin are no longer correct. Check the security configuration on the origin (or ask whoever admins the origin to do so).

Answer (score 2):

In the wake of [GitHub deprecating weak cryptographic standards](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-deprecation-notice/), your own remote repository server (referenced by "origin") might also have deprecated some of those standards.

Which means  your [local openssl might be too old](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30484972/6309).

Comment: yum update openssl , still shows OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: Exactly, try and seek a more recent version

Comment: i get error when i run ./config 
**This system (linux-x86_64) is not supported. See file INSTALL for details.**

Comment: @JinuMohan What is your OS?

Comment: Oracle Linux 6 u3 (Intel 64-bit, Developer)

Comment: So it is FIPS capable (https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/oracle-linux-fips), but using a non-validated cryptography (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30490010/6309). Can you check its FIPS suppoert level? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492776/6309)

Comment: sorry for the delay , i am not sure which exact command you are asking me to run

Comment: @JinuMohan What is written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492776/6309: `cat /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/opensslconf.h  | grep -A 2 -i fips`

Comment: I do not see a directory /usr/local/ssl

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the failure  was happening because git was doing a curl during pull and curl was failing with illegal instruction problem 
https://gryzli.info/2016/05/28/centos-6-curl-ssl-illegal-instruction-error/

once I added export NSS_DISABLE_HW_GCM=1, the git pull worked fine.