# How to check if the openssl libraries are using the FIPS validated crytpography

Tags: windows, openssl, fips

I have open OpenSSL provided binaries from the third party (`libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`). I need to check and verify if those provided run time libraries are using cryptographic algorithms adhering to FIPS 140-2. Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to check this?

Yes, there are a number of ways. The easiest is to run `openssl version` from the command line. If its FIPS validated cryptography, then it will say something like:

```
> openssl version
Version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f-fips 6 Jan 2014
```

---

A related question for doing so on Linux is at [How to check FIPS 140-2 support in OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18616573). Windows is sufficiently different, so this question should remain open.

Though the former question is Linux, you can do the same on Windows using `dumpbin`, `find` and `strings`. Be sure to have a Developer Prompt open (and not a regular command prompt) to ensure tools like dumpbin are on path.

Here are some of the things you can check (from the slide deck discussed below):

- Expected user space symbols are present

  - FIPS_mode_set(), FIPS_module_mode_set(), FIPS_mode(), FIPS_module_mode()
- Expected internal symbols are present

  - FIPS_text_start(), FIPS_text_end(), FIPS_rodata_start[], FIPS_rodata_end[], FIPS_signature[20];
- FIPS_set_mode(1) is called and does not fail

  - ERR_get_error returns 0x0f06d065
  - CRYPTO_R_FIPS_MODE_NOT_SUPPORTED returned FTW!
- Using strings

  - “FIPS 2.0 validated module 14 Mar 2012”
  - “FIPS 2.0.1 validated test module 12 Jun 2012”
  - etc
- Known Answer Tests

  - Binary string data in RO section of executable
  - Check the *.c files for static values
  - Various subdirectories: aes, cmac, des, …, ecdsa, dsa, …
  - Selftest files: aes_selftest.c, dsa_selftes.c, …

Here's an example of the binary string that will be present from `fips/rand/fips_drbg_selftest.h`:

```
0x2e,0xbf,0x98,0xf9,0x85,0x27,0x8b,0xff,
0x36,0xb9,0x40,0x0b,0xc0,0xa1,0xa0,0x13,
0x20,0x06,0xcc,0xe6,0x2a,0x03,0x77,0x7d,
0xee,0xde,0xcc,0x34,0xe3,0xcd,0x77,0xea,
0xd0,0x3e,0xbe,0xdd,0xf6,0x15,0xfb,0xa7,
0xd7,0x8e,0xd0,0x2e,0x2f,0x82,0x4c,0xc7,
0x87,0xb1,0x6f,0xc5,0xf8,0x5c,0x78,0xde,
0x77,0x9b,0x15,0x9a,0xb9,0x3c,0x38,0x38
```

---

I also uploaded a slide deck I have on the subject to the OpenSSL wiki. Its called [Building Applications using OpenSSL Validated Cryptography: Notes from the Field for Developers and Auditors](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/File:Fips-validated-openssl.tar.gz). You will want to review the material starting around Slide 18.

I built the slide deck for [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org) but there's was no interest in receiving it. I know Stack Overflow frowns upon links like the one on the OpenSSL wiki, but I don't know how to provide a 35+ slide deck here.

Comment: Thanks a lot JWW. I used 'dumpbin /ALL libeay32.dll' to get the information about the libeay32.dll. As per you suggested, I checked for the user space symbols and internal symbols. But I could only find the user space symbols and not all the internal symbols in it. Also the strings mentioned are absent from the ssl runtime libeay32.dll.

Comment: 7E1EFCE0: 66 69 70 73 20 6D 6F 64 65 20 61 6C 72 65 61 64  fips mode alread
  7E1EFCF0: 79 20 73 65 74 00 00 00 66 69 6E 67 65 72 70 72  y set...fingerpr7E1EFD00: 69 6E 74 20 64 6F 65 73 20 6E 6F 74 20 6D 61 74  int does not mat
  7E1EFD10: 63 68 20 73 65 67 6D 65 6E 74 20 61 6C 69 61 73  ch segment alias
  7E1EFD20: 69 6E 67 00 66 69 6E 67 65 72 70 72 69 6E 74 20  ing.fingerprint

Comment: so partially validated. Does that mean the ssl runtime are using required cryptography ?

Comment: @SanjayPhanshikar - the validated cryptography is provided by `libcrypto` (I'm not sure what is is called on Windows). `libssl` uses `libcrypto`, so it only depends on `libcrypto` (again, I'm not sure what is is called on Windows). There is some hand waiving because some SSL functionality is affected by FIPS. But it really reduces to `libcrypto`.