# How do I enable FIPS mode in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, openssl, fips

I am hoping to get some guidance on enabling openssl fips mode for nginx.
So far I followed the openssl guide for enabling fips mode on the openssl.

That part works well:

```
# /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl md5 /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl
Error setting digest md5
139805371958952:error:060A80A3:digital envelope 
routines:FIPS_DIGESTINIT:disabled for fips:fips_md.c:180:

# cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
1
```

For nginx I first tried to build nginx using this custom openssl:

```
/nginx-1.12.2/configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl --with-ld-opt="-L/usr/local/openssl/lib"
```

This failed however since the /usr/local/openssl is the "installed" location of custom openssl, not the source tree.

So I changed --with-openssl option to use openssl source tree as:

```
/nginx-1.12.2/configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2n/ --with-ld-opt="-L/usr/local/openssl/lib"
```

This works and I am able to install nginx but I don't think proper openssl compile options to support fips mode
is passed during nginx configure.

When I print nginx info:

```
nginx -V:
nginx version: nginx/1.12.2
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

Yet the custom openssl is:

```
/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2n-fips  7 Dec 2017
```

Do I need to be passing openssl compile option to enable fips support while configuring nginx?

Per "Configurable FIPS mode" thread (https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?10,257298,257298)

> "Currently we solve this by compiling nginx ourselves after adding    FIPS_mode_set(1) after the SSL library initialization code in systems   where we require it."

And per "How to check FIPS 140-2 support in OpenSSL?"([How to check FIPS 140-2 support in OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616573/how-to-check-fips-140-2-support-in-openssl)):

> FIPS could be available but not used. So an application must enable the validated cryptography via  FIPS_mode_set, and the call must succeed.
>   Can someone let me know where to set FIPS_mode_set flag?

I searched for that setting and found one binary obj file under nginx:
nginx-1.12.2/objs/nginx

and a header file under openssl source directories:
openssl-1.0.2n/.openssl/include/openssl/crypto.h

Any help/guidance greatly appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:
As I was checking the output from ../src/nginx-1.12.2/make command, I noticed, it removes original Makefile from ../src/openssl-1.0.2n, along with FIPS related options in it:

> ```
>    cd /usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2n/ \
>
>    && if [ -f Makefile ]; then make clean; fi \
>
>    && ./config --prefix=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2n/.openssl no-shared  \
>
>    && make \
>
>    && make install_sw LIBDIR=lib
>
>    make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2n'
> ```

Any idea about how to pass proper openssl make options to nginx?
Or to configure nginx to use already installed fips capable custom openssl?
Thanks again

Comment: Several years ago I had the same task. Several years ago you had to (1) patch the Nginx build system, and (2) modify the Nginx sources to call `FIPS_mode_set(1)`. I don't know what is needed nowadays.

Comment: I know, I am referencing a thread in the body of mine with your answer with most votes :)
I am trying to hunt down where and how to set "FIPS_mode_set(1)" in Nginx sources prior to building it per your (and some others') answer for earlier questions.

Comment: You call `FIPS_mode_set` after you call `SSL_library_init` or `OPENSSL_init_ssl`. See [Library Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki. The [OpenSSL FIPS Object Module User Guide](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf) also has a section on how to call `FIPS_mode_set`.